# proj.db not found in gdal-3.2.1 runing in Amazon Linux 2

Tags: python, gdal, proj, ogr, osgeo

Even if i've set the PROJ_LIB env variable to the path of proj.db from the terminal and from the code (Python) it still dosen't recognize it. I'm not sure about this but does it have anything to do with the OS which is Amazon Linux 2, because it was working just fine in my dev environment (Windows) and btw i'm not using a virtual env cuz i've found one only way to install GDAL in Amazon Linux 2 and not in a virtual env...